# Run screen touch-event before anchor tag touch loads new web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a website i am showing a popup to display some results by clicking on chat menu button on website. When user touch outside the popup ,it is hidden with animation. But when user touches any anchor property then it does not hide the popup, it loads linked page. And until the new page is fully loading popup is showing on previous page.

```
window.addEventListener('touchStart', function(e) { 
  if(document.getElementById('btnChat').classList.contains('hideChatBtn')){
    if (!document.getElementById('cro-script').contains(e.target)){ 
      jQuery(document).find(".search").hide(600);
      document.getElementById('btnChat').classList.remove('hideChatBtn');
      document.getElementById('btnChat').classList.add("showChatDiv");              
    }
  }
});
```

**Here btnChat is id of chat button and search is the id of popup.**

Comment: You can use this condition `if(e.target.nodeName === 'A')` for `<a>` tags and `e.preventDefault()` to stop click on anchor and store href value in variable. After closing chatbox with animation you can redirect using `window.location.href` to another page.

Comment: Yes but i do not want to use  `window.location.href` . I want <a> to behave normal. Like some code to delay its default behaviour. I am using this popup tool as third party package, that can be used on multiple websites. So `window.location.href` will not work appropriately.

Comment: Can you share demo or page link to look into the code and problem?

Comment: Another idea is.... You can set `e.preventDefault()` for all `<a>` tags when chatbox opened. When you click on `<a>` tag, close chatbox first with animation then unbind click event from all `<a>` tags using `e.unbind('click')`.

Comment: [link] (http://ventureby.com/shop-test)  test this on mobile device

Comment: Chatbox popup has also anchors, and also after `e.unbind('click')` , anchor will not work. User has to click on it again to navigate link